# VLookup using a Workbook that is not Open

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function that opens a workbook that has my lookup table stored and then takes the cell value of the specific position and saves it, however, I have this function repeated multiple times for different VLookup Tables. Is there a way to reference the worksheets without opening the workbook? Essentially, I am looking to replace the `Workbooks.Open` function so it doesn't open all the different workbooks. Here is just a sample of one of the functions that uses the `Workbooks.Open` line

```
Function GetScopeFilename(axsunpart As String, sweeprate As Double) 
Dim wbSrc As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, position As Long

Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\LookupTable.xlsx")
Set ws = wbSrc.Worksheets("Scope Filename")

If sweeprate = 50 Then
    position = 2 
ElseIf sweeprate = 100 Then
    position = 3
ElseIf sweeprate = 200 Then
    position = 4
ElseIf sweeprate = "" Then
    MsgBox "No argument sweep rate value. Can be found. Check before running again."
    'Stop
End If

GetScopeFilename = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(axsunpart, ws.Range("A1:D4"), position, False)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT 2:

I could not find a way to refer to a closed workbook with `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` (I am happy to hear if someone can do it). However, It does work with `VLOOKUP` function, when written in a cell - using [links](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f).

#### 1. Workaround: Links and cell formula - avoid `Workbooks.Open`

Write a formula in an available cell, save value in a variable and clear the cell - e.g. cell `A1`:

```
Function GetScopeFilename(axsunpart As String, sweeprate As Double)
Dim temp_cell As Range, position As Long
set temp_cell = Range("A1") 'choose available cell at the moment

'your if statements here

With temp_cell
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & axsunpart & ",'C:\Users\Documents\[LookupTable.xlsx]Scope Filename'!R1C1:R4C4," & position & ",False)"
    GetScopeFilename = .Value
    .Clear
End With

End Function
```

*Side note: try to use `XLOOKUP` [function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) instead of `VLOOKUP` - a short comparison [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/800574/index-match-vs-vlookup-vs-xlookup/). Basically it's a combination of `VLOOKUP` an `HLOOKUP`.*

#### 2. Open wb outside function - keep `Workbooks.Open`

While the first solution should be faster, in case you prefer not writing in a cell and decide to keep `Workbooks.Open`, it might be good idea to:

> open the workbook outside the function and pass it as a parameter

as pointed by @MathieuGuindon. This is helpful when calling the function multiple times (the search Workbook will be open only once).

Simplified example:

```
Sub main()
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    'other variables omitted for simplicity
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(path_to_file)
    debug.print GetScopeFilename(wbSrc)
end Sub

Function GetScopeFilename(wbSrc As Workbook) 
    'function
end Function
```

Comment: So rather than `Set wbSrc` to equal a workbook, have it be set to `='C:\Users\Documents\[LookupTable.xlsx]Scope Filename' !A1` and then I can keep the rest of my function as the same?

Comment: @resu_student, I misunderstood at first.. I think `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` doesn't work with closed workbooks. On the other hand, `VLOOKUP` function written in a cell works - e.g. `='C:\Users\Documents\[LookupTable.xlsx]Scope Filename'!A1`. Would temporarily writing in a cell and then reading the value from it be an acceptable workaround? If yes, I can update my solution.

Comment: What do you mean by temporarily writing in a cell? For the macro, the workbook I am referencing will be the same the entire time the macro runs.

Comment: @resu_student I editted the answer. Hope it's more clear and helpful.

Comment: Ohh I think I understand, you mean to go into a specific excel cell and then type `=VLOOKUP` using the function and then add the inputs?

Comment: @resu_student Exactly. Does the code solve your problem?

Comment: Does A1 refer to the first cell on sheet `Scope Filename`? So I would have to repeat the line `='C:\Users\Documents\[LookupTable.xlsx]Scope Filename'!A1` for each sheet that I want to use the `VLOOKUP` function?

Comment: _Declare variables outside function, if possible_ - no. Declare variables where they're being used, or as close as possible. If a variable has no business being more than a local variable, then it should be a local variable.

Comment: @resu_student, yes it refers to cell A1 on that specific sheet. If you want to refer to another one, you need to change it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, thanks for feedback. What should be done in this case? He is calling the function multiple times - should variables be declared each time the function is called?

Comment: @simpatak and with your approach wouldnt it still be opening the search workbook? if that is the case then wouldnt it be less lines for me to keep my function as it is?

Comment: I hadn't looked in details, but if what you meant was to actually open the workbook outside the function and pass it as a parameter, then we're totally on the same page ;-)

Comment: @resu_student it's called link (or external reference) and 1. referenced workbook, does not have to be open, hence `Workbooks.Open` is not needed (which was your question); 2. it should be faster than `Workbooks.Open`, especially with large ws https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f. Downside is that this approach needs to write in a cell, which some people might like.